# Referencing .so files from an Android library

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-library

I've built OpenSSL into an Android Library that I would like to reference from another Android project.

Unfortunately,

1. Yes, I do need OpenSSL, as I need to change the behaviour of dependant Android classes not in the public API. (not enough space here)
2. My experience with native code is non-existant.

[image: Built files in OpenSSL Android library project]

The project is selected as a library in Preferences > Android

[image]

This library is referenced from a second Android project

[image]

**My Questions are these**

1. How can I reference the .so files in my Android library from Android.mk in my second project so that I can build dependant files there? I'd prefer not to put the .so files directly in my second project - but if that is the only solution I would accept reasons and directions as an answer.
2. How should I include/reference the .so file in files I am building in the second project?

Surely, it is something simple.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The interface you mentioned above is for Java based libraries not JNI based

Comment: This is what I suspected. I'll try to bring the modules into my second project and build them all there together - Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

once you generate (.so) library file, then make a folder in your applitcation's project folder named "**libs/armeabi/**" put (.so) file in this folder

and in your application write

```
System.loadLibrary("library_name");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - but as I am building dependant modules in my second project, I don't think this is the answer for me.

Comment: I'm searching for the same issue. Do you really have to copy the lib in? An Android project can't reference an externally located .so file?